# Virtual model attribute which links to a record from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Suppose I have `Person` model which has `has_many` association with `PhoneNumber` model. Each person has several phone numbers and one of them is always set as primary number for the person. I implemented this by adding `primary` boolean column in `PhoneNumber` model.

Now I want to make a way to obtain primary number of a person. I've added following method to `Person` model

```
  def primary_number
    self.phone_numbers.each{ |n|   return n if n.primary }
  end
```

However I am concerned about performance of this piece of code (with and without eager loading of the associated model). Is there a better (faster) way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to extend the association:

```
has_many :phone_numbers do
  def primary
    where phone_numbers: { primary: true }
  end
end
```

and then use:

```
person.phone_numbers.primary
```